# Way to enable Chrome flags in CSS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html, web

If you go to

chrome://flags/

in your Chrome web browser, there is an option to enable "Smooth Scrolling". Is there a way to have my website enable this if it detects that the user is using Chrome as the browser? Firefox already has smooth scrolling on by default to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: i don't think thats possible. it would be a huge security risk.

Comment: as @DanielA.White said that would be a security risk. Although this is a firefox example, there is probably a similar thing in chrome: webGL. There used to be some security bug or other with it. You could enable it in the `about:config` page, but if websites could do that: security

Comment: you can manually make smooth scrolling by cancelling scroll event and scrolling the page via javascript and cancelling 200px hiccups.

Comment: You could ask your users nicely to go to the chrome://flags/ page and set it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, you can use some of the libraries to achieve that. For example this one I found as cool

https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/jquery.smoothwheel